# Pass data.table column by name in function

Tags: r, data.table

I want to pass a column name to a function and use column indexing and the `setorder` function:

```
require(data.table)
data(iris)

top3 = function(t, n) {
  setorder(t, n, order=-1)
  return ( t[1:3, .(Species, n)])
}

DT = data.table(iris)
top3(DT, Petal.Width)
```

However, this returns an error:

`Error in setorderv(x, cols, order, na.last) : 
  some columns are not in the data.table: n,1`

I think I'm misunderstanding how passing bare column names works in R.  What are my options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do

```
top3 = function(DT, nm) eval(substitute( DT[order(-nm), .(Species, nm)][, head(.SD, 3L)] ))
top3(DT, Petal.Width)

     Species Petal.Width
1: virginica         2.5
2: virginica         2.5
3: virginica         2.5
```

I would advise against (1) `setorder` inside a function, since it has side effects; (2) indexing with `1:3` when you may use this on a data.table with fewer than three rows in the future, to strange effect; (3) fixing `3` instead of making it an argument to the function; and (4) using `n` for name... just my personal preference to reserve `n` for counts.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your dataset will always have more than 3 rows and that this is the ONLY operation you want to perform on that data table, it may be in your interest to use `setorderv` instead.

```
top3 = function(t, n) {
  setorderv(t, n, -1)
  return ( t[1:3, c("Species", n), with=FALSE])
}

DT = data.table(iris)
top3(DT, "Petal.Width")
```

Result:

```
     Species Petal.Width
1: virginica         2.5
2: virginica         2.5
3: virginica         2.5
```